# MongoDB Aggregation: add field from an embedded document via a dynamic field path

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregation pipeline and am stuck on a stage. At this point I have a document in the following format:

```
{
  _id:ObjectId(5e3d326637df7e4dda73ec22),
  levelName:"Level 1",
  levelNames: {
    "Level 1":"5e567993b6ed4b7b4d2c044d"
    "Level 2":"5e567996a7826d45f836dfa3"
    "Level 3":"5e5679991f515a01c73e9006"
  }
}
```

and I want to add an $addField/$set stage which gives me the ID value of the entry in the levelNames object with a key matching the levelName property of the root document.

I've been trying to use some sort of dynamic field path ($concat: ["levelNames.", "$levelName"]) but have had no luck. This is my $addField stage:

```
/**
 * newField: The new field name.
 * expression: The new field expression.
 */
{
  currentLevelId: {
    $let: {
      vars: {
        levelPath: {
          $concat: ["levelNames.", "$levelName"]
        }
      },
      in: {
        currentLevelId: "$$levelPath"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the result I get is:

```
{
  _id:ObjectId(5e3d326637df7e4dda73ec22),
  levelName:"Level 1",
  levelNames: {
    "Level 1":"5e567993b6ed4b7b4d2c044d"
    "Level 2":"5e567996a7826d45f836dfa3"
    "Level 3":"5e5679991f515a01c73e9006"
  }
  currentLevelId: {
    currentLevelId:"levelNames.Level 1"
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get the result of currentLevelId to be "5e567993b6ed4b7b4d2c044d", so my desired output is:

```
{
  _id:ObjectId(5e3d326637df7e4dda73ec22),
  levelName:"Level 1",
  levelNames: {
    "Level 1":"5e567993b6ed4b7b4d2c044d"
    "Level 2":"5e567996a7826d45f836dfa3"
    "Level 3":"5e5679991f515a01c73e9006"
  },
  currentLevelId: "5e567993b6ed4b7b4d2c044d"
}
```

Is there a way this can be achieved?

Comment: Can you show me the example result of your aggregation?

Comment: @bravemaster no problem, I've updated the question.

Comment: can you also updated your desired output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $set: { data: { $objectToArray: "$levelNames" } } },
   {
      $set: {
         currentLevelId: {
            $arrayElemAt: ["$data.v", { $indexOfArray: ["$data.k", "$levelName"] }]
         }
      }
   },
   { $unset: "data" }
])
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/p_raCM17L51)

Comment: Is there a way to get a value directly from `levelNames` instead of casting it to array and get index of `levelName`?

Comment: I don't think so as the field names are dynamic and not known at design time.

Comment: Indeed, field path names may not start with '$'.

Comment: Thanks @WernfriedDomscheit – that works perfectly in the playground, but when I run it on my machine I get the following error in the first stage: 

"object [{"_bsontype":"ObjectID","id":{"0":94,"1":86,"2":121,"3":132,"4":167,"5":130,"6":109,"7":69,"8":248,"9":54,"10":223,"11":162}}] is not a valid ObjectId"

Might be an issue with the version of Mongo I'm running?

Comment: Do you have `ObjectId` objects or strings as data?

Comment: It seems to be a bug with MongoDB Compass – works fine in the shell. This is all working, thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the aggregation query,

*

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            warehouses: { $objectToArray: "$levelNames" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            levelName: 1,
            levelNames: 1,
            currentLevelId: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$warehouses",
                    as: "item",
                    cond: { $eq: ["$$item.k", "$levelName"] }
                }
            },
        }
    },
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: ["$$ROOT", { $arrayElemAt: ["$currentLevelId", 0] }] } } },
    {
        $project: {
            currentLevelId: "$v",
            levelName: true,
            levelNames: true,
        }
    }
])
```

*

Comment: Thanks Nikhil – I went with Wernfried's answer but this looks good too, much appreciated.