# Mongodb having problem of adding two values inside nested document with dynamic key

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I wish to add currentAsset.total and longTermAsset.total for each of my child documents with dynamic key to a new field. My current mongodb version is 4.0.12

My source document is as below:

```js
{
   "_id":"5f44bc4c36ac3e2c8c6db4bd",
   "counter":"Apple",
   "balancesheet":{
      "0":{
         "currentAsset":{
            "total":123.12
         },
         "longTermAsset":{
            "total":10.16
         }
      },
      "1":{
         "currentAsset":{
            "total":10.23
         },
         "longTermAsset":{
            "total":36.28
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The result document I wanted to get is:

```js
{
    "_id": "5f44bc4c36ac3e2c8c6db4bd",
    "counter": "Apple",
    "balancesheet": {
        "0": {
            "currentAsset": {
                "total": 123.12
            },
            "longTermAsset": {
                "total": 10.16
            },
            "totalAsset": 133.28
        },
        "1": {
            "currentAsset": {
                "total": 10.23
            },
            "longTermAsset": {
                "total": 36.28
            },
            "totalAsset": 46.51
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried a few aggegrates but failed as it is giving me "errmsg" : "$add only supports numeric or date types, not array"

```js
db.balancesheets.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { counter: "Apple" }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            bs: { $objectToArray: "$balancesheet" }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            totalAsset: {
                $add: ["$bs.k.currentAsset.total", "$bs.k.longTermAsset.total"]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

As I refer to this, it seems like the version needs to be 4.2 and above. Is there anyway that will be able to do it on my existing 4.0.12 version?
[MongoDB Aggregation: add field from an embedded document via a dynamic field path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60448849/mongodb-aggregation-add-field-from-an-embedded-document-via-a-dynamic-field-pat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no version issues, follow few fixes,

- first 2 pipelines looks good,
- `$unwind` deconstruct `bs` array
- `$addFields` corrected, you used k instead of v in accessing field total
- `$group` to reconstruct and prepare again object to array
- `$addFields` to convert bs array to object using `$reduce`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  // $match ... pipeline
  // $project ... pipeline

  // unwind bs array
  { $unwind: "$bs" },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "bs.v.totalAsset": { $add: ["$bs.v.currentAsset.total", "$bs.v.longTermAsset.total"] }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      bs: { $push: { $arrayToObject: [["$bs"]] } },
      counter: { $first: "$counter" },
    },
  }
  {
    $addFields: {
      bs: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$bs",
          initialValue: {},
          in: { $mergeObjects: ["$$value", "$$this"] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/w_Y7mndEPA-)

Comment: Nice...thank you. I modified a bit to suit my case where i added in counter for $project and added $first inside $group for counter. Is this correct or are there any better way of doing it?

https://mongoplayground.net/p/G-HO0Gff7a0

Comment: yes this is correct way, and this is returning bs array instead of objects, even in my example will correct and update you