# Create Dynamic Field Names based on nested arrays MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, aggregation-framework

I need to flatten out our data structure so that Elastic Search is more easily able to index the documents (I'm also looking at MongoDB Atlas Search for this).

Our current structure is

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "60f83d3cd66842301905aa77"
  },
  "id": 527438,
  "name": "CryptoPunk #4050",
  "asset_contract": {
    "name": "CryptoPunks",
    "address": "0xb47e3cd837ddf8e4c57f05d70ab865de6e193bbb"
  },
  "traits": [
    {
      "trait_type": "type",
      "value": "Male",
      "display_type": null,
      "max_value": null,
      "trait_count": 6039,
      "order": null
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "accessory",
      "value": "Mohawk",
      "display_type": null,
      "max_value": null,
      "trait_count": 441,
      "order": null
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "accessory",
      "value": "Earring",
      "display_type": null,
      "max_value": null,
      "trait_count": 2459,
      "order": null
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "accessory",
      "value": "Frown",
      "display_type": null,
      "max_value": null,
      "trait_count": 261,
      "order": null
    }
  ],
  "token_id": "4050",
}
```

What I'd like to do is flatten out the structure to look like

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "60f83d3cd66842301905aa77"
  },
  "id": 527438,
  "name": "CryptoPunk #4050",
  "asset_contract": {
    "name": "CryptoPunks",
    "address": "0xb47e3cd837ddf8e4c57f05d70ab865de6e193bbb"
  },
  "traits_type": "Male",
  "traits_accessory": ["Mohawk", "Earring", "Frown"],
  "token_id": "4050",
}
```

The contents on the `traits` array will vary. Sometimes there will be 1 trait within the array, sometimes there will be multiple items of the same trait type (like `accessory` in this example), and other times there could be 10 items in there each with their own `trait_type`.

The basic rule I think I want to follow is...

- When there traits, create a new field using `traits_"$trait_type"` as the field name, and use the `$value` as the new field name value.
- If there are multiple matches for `traits_"$trait_type"`, then `$push` them into an array (as in the example above).

I've looked at this solution [MongoDB Aggregation: add field from an embedded document via a dynamic field path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60448849/mongodb-aggregation-add-field-from-an-embedded-document-via-a-dynamic-field-pat) but I'm having trouble getting it to go a level deeper.

***EDIT FOR FURTHER CLARIFICATION***

Here is another document example that should be transformed using the same logic.

```json
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60f83d3cbc3f0161da2141f7"
    },
    "id": 17736625,
    "name": "OJ Simpson",
    "asset_contract": {
        "name": "Hashmasks",
        "address": "0xc2c747e0f7004f9e8817db2ca4997657a7746928"
    },
    "traits": [
        {
            "trait_type": "Character",
            "value": "Male",
            "display_type": null,
            "max_value": null,
            "trait_count": 8659,
            "order": null
        },
        {
            "trait_type": "Mask",
            "value": "Doodle",
            "display_type": null,
            "max_value": null,
            "trait_count": 2187,
            "order": null
        },
        {
            "trait_type": "Eye Color",
            "value": "Dark",
            "display_type": null,
            "max_value": null,
            "trait_count": 7419,
            "order": null
        },
        {
            "trait_type": "Item",
            "value": "No Item",
            "display_type": null,
            "max_value": null,
            "trait_count": 14533,
            "order": null
        },
        {
            "trait_type": "Skin Color",
            "value": "Dark",
            "display_type": null,
            "max_value": null,
            "trait_count": 3784,
            "order": null
        },
        {
            "trait_type": "Token ID",
            "value": 3535,
            "display_type": "number",
            "max_value": null,
            "trait_count": 0,
            "order": null
        },
        {
            "trait_type": "Background",
            "value": "Doodle",
            "display_type": null,
            "max_value": null,
            "trait_count": 5538,
            "order": null
        }
    ],
    "token_id": "3535"
}
```

This document comes from a different document contract but maintains the same stucture, albeit with a different set of and number of traits.  The change to fields remains the same process though...

1. rename the trait type to `traits_$trait_type`
2. set the value of this new field to the `$value` of that trait
3. include this field on the top level

Here is how this should look after the transform

```json
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60f83d3cbc3f0161da2141f7"
    },
    "id": 17736625,
    "name": "OJ Simpson",
    "asset_contract": {
        "name": "Hashmasks",
        "address": "0xc2c747e0f7004f9e8817db2ca4997657a7746928"
    },
    "traits_character": "Male",
    "traits_mask": "Doodle",
    "traits_eye_color": "Dark",
    "traits_item": "No Item",
    "traits_skin_color": "Dark",
    "traits_token_id": 3535,
    "traits_background": "Doodle",
    "token_id": "3535"
}
```

The structure of the document will always be similar in that there is always a `traits` array, and we want to move that array up onto the top level with the name relating to the `trait_type` and the value relating to the `value`. Where there are multiple instances of the same `trait_type` we want to push those values into an array.

Comment: In the document result, how is trait_type determined? All traits have 1 not-accessory member and all others are accesory?And the not-accesory member defines the trait_type like the abover example?Or it possible to have only accesory members or only not-accesory members?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but I'll try and clarify by updating with another example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving data on keys, makes it more complicated, because we have to do things like `$objectToArray` [see this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68884011/aggregating-a-total-from-subdocuments-in-mongodb/68884209#68884209)

For each trait in traits array adds 1 field to the eternal document.
`{"trait_$value" : ["$value1" "$value2"]}` if trait had many values
of
`{"trait_$value" : "$value1"}` if trait had 1 value only

`("trait_$value" gets lower-case and replace spaces with "_" also)`

**Query** (works on your data and produce results with data on keys)

If you look at the code example we have 2 collections, your collection, and one dummy c2=[{}], we need this to make the `$lookup`
so we can use the stage operator like `$group` dont delete it, just add this dummy 1 empty document collection to the database.

Because we had to do things like `$group` it was not possible to do it with update, there are 2 solutions

- add an `$out` stage to the aggregation (output to new collection and replace it)
- add a `$merge` stage to the aggregation, that works like an update

Example data1
[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bmC03qKe5ct)

Example data2 (i added 1 eye_color to make an array)
[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nrvHsP_obug)

Query

- `$lookup` with a dummy collection `[{}]` reason to do that is to use stage operators inside 1 document to avoid things like unwind-group (we need to group that traits array)
- Inside the lookup pipeline (in the pipeline its just the ROOT doc)
- unwind traits (each traite separate document)
- group by trait_type, collect the values
  `{"_id" : type1 "values" [value1 ...]}`
  `{"_id" : type2 "values" [value1 ...]}`
- now on that we change
  `{"_id" : type1 "values" [value1 ...]}`
  to `(object to array $$ROOT)`
  [["traits_type1" [value1 ...]]]  (if 1 value we dont have array)
  to `(array to object $$pair)`
  {"traits_type1" : [value1 ...]}
- the next is making that array "traits" output of lookup to object
- and add it back to the root

```js
db.c1.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "c2",
      "let": {
        "traits": "$traits"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$addFields": {
            "traits": "$$traits"
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "traits": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "$unwind": {
            "path": "$traits"
          }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$traits.trait_type",
            "values": {
              "$push": "$traits.value"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$replaceRoot": {
            "newRoot": {
              "$let": {
                "vars": {
                  "r": {
                    "$map": {
                      "input": {
                        "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
                      },
                      "as": "m",
                      "in": [
                        "$$m.k",
                        "$$m.v"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                },
                "in": {
                  "$let": {
                    "vars": {
                      "pair": [
                        [
                          {
                            "$replaceAll": {
                              "input": {
                                "$concat": [
                                  "traits_",
                                  {
                                    "$toLower": {
                                      "$arrayElemAt": [
                                        {
                                          "$arrayElemAt": [
                                            "$$r",
                                            0
                                          ]
                                        },
                                        1
                                      ]
                                    }
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              "find": " ",
                              "replacement": "_"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "$let": {
                              "vars": {
                                "v": {
                                  "$arrayElemAt": [
                                    {
                                      "$arrayElemAt": [
                                        "$$r",
                                        1
                                      ]
                                    },
                                    1
                                  ]
                                }
                              },
                              "in": {
                                "$cond": [
                                  {
                                    "$eq": [
                                      {
                                        "$size": "$$v"
                                      },
                                      1
                                    ]
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "$arrayElemAt": [
                                      "$$v",
                                      0
                                    ]
                                  },
                                  "$$v"
                                ]
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      ]
                    },
                    "in": {
                      "$arrayToObject": "$$pair"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "traits"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "traits": {
        "$arrayToObject": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$traits",
            "as": "t",
            "in": {
              "$arrayElemAt": [
                {
                  "$map": {
                    "input": {
                      "$objectToArray": "$$t"
                    },
                    "as": "m",
                    "in": [
                      "$$m.k",
                      "$$m.v"
                    ]
                  }
                },
                0
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$traits",
          "$$ROOT"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "traits": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: I might be wrong but "Dynamic Field Names" implies names of the fields like "traits_type" and "traits_accessory" are not known beforehand and should be calculated runtime ("type" and "accessory" parts come from "traits_type" field in the original document). OP included a link to the similar question where ArrayToObject is used to achieve it. If I get it, OP struggles to apply this technic to subdocuments.

Comment: Thank you, the immediate thing I noticed is that this code specifically has "$traits_type" and "$traits_accessory" which I don't think will work as there are different variations of the "$trait_type"

Comment: ok i changed the query, to work on dynamic types.

Comment: @Takis_ this is amazing, thank you so much.  Last request, but it's not just the `traits_accessory` that could have multiple instances that we want to put into an array, it _could_ be any of the `trait` options. I'm super impressed by your knowledge!

Comment: ok i updated it, i think this time will be ok

Comment: @Takis_ this was really helpful. I've got some other data adjustments I'd like to make, can you dm me on (at)justinavery on twitter to arrange something? I'm interested to understand what the bits are doing and happy to reward your time and effort.

Comment: @justinavery happy it helped, i added more information on how query works, if you post a new question, and i can help i will reply, tag me if you want : ) , query is not really hard, the JSON makes it look harder than it is.

Comment: @Takis_ I'm going through your explanation to try and decipher what needs to be updated, and in the meantime I'd already written the problem out on our wiki so have reposted it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69080500/mongodb-aggregation-data-manipulation-objects-to-arrays - any help appreciated (and will bounty it for you too).